# On Wavefunctions of Hydrogen atom

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

In the context of the wave functions of electron in a hydrogen atom, I just want to get clear regarding the terms **probability** and **probability density** of an finding an electron. To be precise, we know that the value of $|\Psi|^2$ at a point gives the *probability density* of the electron at the point. Now, does that imply that if the value of $|\Psi|^2$ is maximum at a point, the electron is most likely to be found at that point?

**Reason for my doubt:** The question given by my instructor goes:

> Given that the normalized wave fuction of the electron in $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbital of an Hydrogen atom is:
>   $$
> \Psi = N \sigma^2 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\sigma}{3}}(3\cos^2\theta-1) \, ,
> $$
>   where $\sigma={\frac{r}{a_o}}$
>
> Now where is the electron most likely to be found?

The solution given goes like:
If $P$ represents probability of finding the electron and $\mathrm{d}V$ the volume element then,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}V} = |\Psi|^2
\implies
\mathrm{d}P=|\Psi|^2 \mathrm{d}V$$
Also since,
$$\mathrm{d}V = r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi$$
We get,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}P &= |\Psi|^2 r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi \\
&= N_1 \sigma^4 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\sigma}{3}}{(3\cos^2\theta-1)^2} \sigma^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\sigma \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi \\
& = N_1 [ \sigma^6 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\sigma}{3}} \mathrm{d}\sigma ][ {(3\cos^2\theta-1)^2} \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta ][ \mathrm{d}\phi]
\end{align}

He later maximized the $[\sigma^6 \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\sigma}{3}}]$ and $[{(3\cos^2\theta-1)^2} \sin{\theta}]$ terms to get the values of ${\sigma}$ *i.e.* hence $r$ and ${\theta}$ at which the electron is most likely to be found. Infact, he stressed on the maximization of ${\theta}$ part which came out to be $0$. And hence, a conclusion made that *for an electron in $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbital, the electron is most likely to be found in the XY plane*.

I find all this stuff confused and fishy. Can someone explain me this solution or prove it wrong *via* a right way of solving this question.

Comment: I thought the difference between probability and probability *density* is that the former is a value while the latter is a function....

Comment: @DHMO So, how does the solution to the question go. Are the conclusions right?

Comment: I made an attempt to improve math expressions a bit. Note to OP: the probability density is $|\Psi|^2$ and *not* $|\Psi^2|$. I'm not sure if the later is even defined for a complex-valued function. :)

Comment: I can assure you, $|\Psi|^2$ and $|\Psi^2|$ are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I don't think so. Show me the definition of the square or a complex number. I've never seen it.

Comment: @Wildcat The square of a complex number is that number multiplied by itself. You can multiply arbitrary complex numbers, can't you?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, please, show me any credible source where $c^2$ is defined.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, cause if you define the square of a complex number $c=a+b\mathrm{i}$ as $c^2:=c \cdot c$, then $|c|^2 \neq |c^2|$ since $|c|^2:=c^* \cdot c=a^2+b^2$ while $|c^2| :=c \cdot c = |a^2+2ab\mathrm{i}-b^2|$.

Comment: Now that's totally right, and these two expressions are in fact equal! See, $|c^2| = |a^2+2ab\mathrm{i}-b^2|=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2}=\sqrt{a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2+4a^2b^2}=\sqrt{a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2}=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46574/discussion-between-wildcat-and-ivan-neretin).

Answer (score 6):

> Now, does that imply that if the value of $|\Psi|^2$ is maximum at a
>   point, the electron is most likely to be found at that point?

It certainly does imply something similar to what OP is saying, but not quite. As always in quantum theory one has to be very careful with his or her wordings. Namely, we are talking about a *continuous* random variable here, so the only probability which makes sense is that of it falling within a particular *range* of values, i.e. probability of finding an electron in some infinitesimal element of volume $\mathrm{d}V$ centered at a particular location $r$ and *not* on this single point. Still, if you divide the whole space into volume elements of an identical (infinitesimally small) size, the bigger the value of $|\Psi|^2$ is, the bigger is the above mentioned probability.

---

Now to the actual findings. So, for an electron occupying the $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbital, the probability of finding it in an infinitesimal element of volume $\mathrm{d}V$ centered at a particular location $r$ is given as $|\Psi|^2 \mathrm{d}V$, where $|\Psi|^2$ is the probability density. We analyze the probability density 
$$
|\Psi|^2
=
N^2 \sigma^4 \mathrm{e}^{-2\sigma/3} (3\cos^2\theta-1)^2 \, ,
$$
or, more precisely only its angular $(3\cos^2\theta-1)^2$ part. So, when does this expression have its maximum value? The global maxima are at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$, i.e. alongside $z$-axis, plus there are local maxima at $\theta = \pi/2$ and $\theta = 3\pi/2$, i.e. in a plane perpendicular to $z$-axis. <sup>1</sup>

[image]

---

From the discussion with OP, it seems it must be noted that terms "probability density" and "probability" are defined *with respect to a particular random event*. Above we analyzed the probability density of finding an electron in an infinitesimal element of volume $\mathrm{d}V$ centered at a point $r$. The radial distribution function arises when considering a probability of a different event, namely, the probability of finding an electron between two concentric spheres of radii $r$ and $r + \mathrm{d}r$. We start from the probability of finding an electron in infinitesimal volume element $\mathrm{d}V$ at a point $r$
$$
  |\Psi|^2 \mathrm{d}V
  =
  \underbrace{R_{nl}^2(r) |Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)|^2}_{|\Psi|^2}
  \underbrace{r^2 \mathrm{d}r \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi}_{\mathrm{d}V} \, ,
$$
and integrate out $\theta$ and $\phi$ dependences
$$
  \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}
  |\Psi|^2 \mathrm{d}V
  =
  \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}
  R_{nl}^2(r) |Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)|^2
  r^2 \mathrm{d}r \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi \, .
$$
And since the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m$ are normalized (to unity)
$$
  \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}
  |Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)|^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi
  =
  1 \, ,
$$
for the probability of finding an electron between two concentric spheres of radii $r$ and $r + \mathrm{d}r$ we simply get
$$
  R_{nl}^2(r) r^2 \mathrm{d}r \, .
$$
The corresponding probability density is, of course, $R_{nl}^2(r) r^2$. Such analysis is different from what we did above for the angular $\theta$ dependence: we simply ignored the radial and the other angular dependence instead of integrating them out. This ignorance makes our analysis a bit rough, but not worthless: at least we were able to identify some general trends in the angular $\theta$ dependence.

---

1) See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3cos%5E2(%CE%B8)%E2%88%921)%5E2) for details.

Comment: I'm going fine through the mathematics and I agree to your idea. But I doubt the way the question was solved. If the same idea is applied for an electron in 1s orbital, wouldn't we get that sin{\theta} should be maximum for the probability to be maximum in an infinitesimal dV volume element around that point. Now which would imply {\theta}=pi/2. Don't these conclusions seems counter-intuitive or awkward in the sense that in a 1s orbital, the probability of finding an electron in a dV volume element should be spherically symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake: $\sin\theta$ should not have been counted in the probability calculations, since it is a part of $\mathrm{d}V$.

Comment: This particular mistake was in the question itself in the first place. @user104014, your intuition serves you right: the whole thing was clear as mud.

Comment: BTW, I think that the conclusion that an electron in $\mathrm{3d}_{z^2}$ orbital is most likely to be found in the $xy$-plane is *wrong*. It is certainly likely that it will be there, but even more likely it will be somewhere along the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Ok! Let's leave this solution for a while. Now how you would have approached to this question. Like, when you get the wavefunction of an electron in an orbital (say 1s or 3dz2), then what conclusions can you make (in regard to electron's probability to find).

Comment: @user104014 I'd write along the same lines, except I'd point out in the answer itself from the very beginning that including $r^2\sin\theta$ was plain wrong, precisely for the reason illustrated in your first comment.

Comment: @Wildcat Even I have the same intuition as in your last comment. But the analysis gave us that {\theta}=pi/2 is the global max. Whats happening. If the methodology followed in the solution mentioned by me in the question is wrong, what is the right one?

Comment: I agree with @Ivan: OP went wrong on including parts of the $\mathrm{d}V$ in the probability calculations. $r^2 \sin\theta$ play exact same role as $\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi$: they are parts of the differential $\mathrm{d}V$ that indicates the *variable of integration*, and *not* parts of the integrand.

Comment: Yes, @user104014, you wrongly included $r^2 \sin\theta$ into the integrand.

Comment: @Ivan OK! If the inclusion of $r^2\sin\theta$ is wrong, then I have two arguments. One that if we don't take that term, then we will end up maximizing probability *density* which  doesn't seem to be correct (or atleast I think so). Second, if you don't include that term, then in case of 1s orbital, you won't get that for $r=a_o$ *i.e.* the bohr radius, the probability of finding the electron is max. Instead we'll get that $r=0$ is where electron is more likely to be found.

Comment: Maximizing probability density, though it has no immediate physical meaning, at least might give you an insight at what the whole 3D density plot looks like. Maximizing _probability density times $r^2\sin\theta$_ has no meaning whatsoever. As for 1s, that's right, the probability density has a maximum at the origin. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @user104014, you need to analyze the probability density. There is absolutely no need at all to consider what the element of volume $\mathrm{d}V$ is.

Comment: Why do you all say that $dV$ should not be included?

Comment: Because it is not a part of the probability density.

Comment: @Ivan Then for 1s, why do many books find the radial probability distrubution function i.e. $4pir^2dr{{\psi}^2}$ and then conclude that this function is max at bohr radius i.e. 0.529 A° nearly. What all this stuff then?

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you talking about, but the so-called radial distribution function $P(r)$ does *not* contain $\mathrm{d}r$. $P(r) \mathrm{d}r$ gives you the probability of finding electron at a distance between $r$ and $r+\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: @user104014 Because, I suppose, they are interested in that _radial_ probability distribution. To obtain it, you take the overall probability density and integrate over all possible values of $\varphi$ and $\theta$, thus making these two go away. Mind you, during integration you **will** introduce $r^2\sin\theta$.

Comment: @Wildcat As Ivan mentioned just now, why are we introducing ${r^2}\sin{\theta}$ in case of radial distribution functions?

Comment: @user104014, it seems like you're completely lost in the topic. :| To get the radial distribution function you need to integrate out the angular dependencies, so you need to "resolve" $\mathrm{d}V$ as $r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi$ for the purpose of the integration. Here we're doing a different analysis: we just look at the angular part of the probability distribution $|\Psi|^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Wildcat, I did not realise that we need to leave out the dependence in the volume.

Comment: Please try to avoid extended discussions in the comments section. You can use [chat] or open a chatroom yourself. Since the discussion seems to have ended, I refrain from transferring it to a chatroom of its own. If that is not the case, flag this comment and ask to transfer comments to a chatroom. (cc @user104014)

Answer (score 2):

Although you ask about hydrogen atoms the same principle is true for any wavefunction.  In quantum mechanics we often need to find the probability at some position *x*. However, *x* is a continuous variable with an infinite number of values so it does not make sense to ask what is the probability of being at some *exact* position, say $x=2/3$, as this will be vanishingly small.

Instead we imagine that the probability is that of being at position *x* to $x+dx$ where *dx* has some very small value. Suppose there is some general function $f(x)$ from we wish to find the probability density then $f(x)dx $ is probability of being between *x* and $x+dx$ and $f(x)$ is the probability density which must be a real,  non-negative number. It turns out that quantum mechanics postulates that the probability density is given in terms of the wavefunction is $|\psi|^2$ and the $|~|$ means take the absolute value. If the wavefunction is a complex quantity, and it often is, then we write $\psi^*\psi$, where the * indicates the complex conjugate of the wavefunction $\psi$, i.e. replace *i* with $-i$ . Finding the maximum of the probability density is done in the same way as you would find the maximum/minimum  of any function, differentiate, set equal to zero and solve. Check if maximum or minimum.

Comment: I agree to everything you said. But if why are we maximizing probability density? If thats the case, for an electron in 1s orbital, shouldn't it be that the electron is more likely to be found at the center, i.e. the nucleus instead of thr bohr radius? [because for 1s orbital, the wavefunction is an exponentially decreasing function like $ke^(-r)$]

Comment: Notice that for your d-orbital, the wave function is actually something like $r^{2}e^{-r^{2}}$. The maximum value of the norm will occur at some non zero value of $r$.

Comment: The atomic wavefunctions are often defined in  spherical polar coordinates and so the volume element over which to integrate is in three dimensions and is $r^2\sin (\theta )dr d\theta d\phi$. The radial part can be separated out and the volume element is therefore  $r^2dr$ which means that the probability is not at zero. For the 1s orbital the probability of being at *r* to $r+dr$ is $(4/a_0^3) r^2\exp(-2r/a_0)dr$  where $a_o$ is the Bohr radius.

Comment: @porphyrin Exactly, thats where my doubt is! If we know seperate the angular part, we'll be left with $\sin{\theta}d{\theta}d{\phi}$. Now maximizing this gives us ${\theta}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Whats this?

Comment: You asked specifically about the radial part. I should have mentioned that to calculate the total probability of finding an electron at *r* to $r+dr$, say in 1s orbital for simplicity, we need to account for the angular parts also, and do this by integrating over them as we seek radial probability, $r^2dr\int_0^{\pi}\sin(\theta)d\theta\int _0^{2\pi}\psi ^*(r,\theta ,\phi)\psi(r,\theta ,\phi) d\phi = (4/a_0^3)r^2\exp(-2r/a_0)dr $

Comment: as to the angular probability this is $\sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi \int _o^\infty r^2\exp(-2r/a_o)dr =(a_0^3/4) \sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi $ (probability of being in that small volume element) and the angular probability density (the 'shape' of the orbital in a plot) is therefore $a_0^3/4$ a constant as expected for a sphere.